# BizTalk Config: A way to set integer infinity as an appSettings value?

Tags: c#, configuration, biztalk, biztalk-2010

I need to read the expirationTime for a Dictionary off the BizTalk configuration. Is there a way to set an appSettings value for a particular key to integer infinity, or the maximum integer? The value is taken inside the C# implementation with the conventional use of `ConfigurationManager.GetAppSettings("expirationTime");`. 
Help, please?

Comment: If the expire time is the end of time, why even haven an expiration time?

Comment: Quite often if you have an integer limit value, setting it to zero denotes that there is no limit.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf Thank you, that was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite often if you have an integer limit value, setting it to zero denotes that there is no limit.

Answer (score 1):

MaxInt is 2,147,483,647.  So, there's your value.